# I uninstalled the bluetooth from linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, bluetooth, bluez

I accidentally uninstalled the bluetooth from my linux mint. and now i am not able to re-install again.

I tried with : `sudo apt-get install bluetooth bluez bluez-tools rfkill rfcomm` the error I received is `Unable to locate package rfcomm`

"and blueman isn't opening at all"

any help please?

Comment: what did you do to delete bluetooth?

Comment: Bluetooth => Uninstall

Answer (score 1):

The `bluez` package provide the `rfcomm` configuration utility, you don't need to install it with the exact name.

here is how to know witch package provide the `rfcomm` command:

```
sudo apt install apt-file 
sudo apt-file update
apt-file search rfcomm
```

or

```
apt-file search /usr/bin/rfcomm

bluez: /usr/bin/rfcomm                    
bluez-tests: /usr/bin/rfcomm-tester
```